# Output 1 if greater than certain threshold and 0 less than another threshold and ignore if in between these threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume I have an array

```
arr = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
```

I have two thresholds threshold1=0.25 and threshold2=0.35

I need to output an array which generates [0, 0, 1, 1]. If value in array arr is less than threshold1, then output array element should be 0 and if greater than threshold2, it should output 1.

I know a one liner code like `output= [0 if x < threshold else 1 for x in arr]` but this generates 5 element output and is not correct. What is the correct way of doing this in one line?

I am expecting output [0, 0, 1, 1].

Comment: You can't use elif in one-liner like that. That should be `else`.

Comment: You input list (it's not an array) has 5 elements but your expected output has 4 elements. Why is that? Also, did you notice the syntax error?

Comment: Corrected the syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add filter condition in a list comprehension:

```
arr = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

threshold1=0.25
threshold2=0.35

output= [0 if x < threshold1 else 1 for x in arr if x < threshold1 or x > threshold2]

print(output) # [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
[x for x in [0 if y < threshold1 else 
             1 if y > threshold2 else None for y in arr] if x is not None]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```